# How can I draw google map using api v3 with multiple locations (address as well as zip codes)?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am in a situation where I need to draw Google map using api v3 with multiple locations. These location can be static address string like "New Delhi, India" or 110005, but they will be several in numbers - can be comma separated or an array - i dont know exactly how they need to be put in the code. But simply i want to draw gmap with multiple locations, so a given map will have 9 or 10 location at once. How to do that? Can you please give me any working code on jsfiddle. For now my code to draw a gmap with only a single location (address only and not zip code) is given below -

**JavaScript -**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&amp;sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var geocoder;
var map;
var marker;
function initialize() 
{
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var myOptions = {
    zoom: 15,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
}

function codeAddress()
{
    //var address = "Talwara Township, Punjab";
    var address = document.getElementById("txtaddress").value;
    geocoder.geocode({'address': address}, function(results, status){       
        if(status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK)
        {
            map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: results[0].geometry.location
            });

            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: "New Delhi, India"
            });
            infowindow.open(map, marker);

            // Click the marker to Zoom to 9
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                map.setZoom(9);
                map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
            });
        } 
    });
}
</script>
```

**HTML -**

```
<body onLoad="initialize();codeAddress();">
<form method="get" action="">
<input type="text" id="txtaddress" name="txtaddress" size="30" value="New Delhi, India" />
<input type="submit" name="btnsubmit" value="Generate Map" />
</form>
<br /><br />
<div id="map_canvas" style="width:500px; height:380px; border:1px solid #AFAFAF;"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking is **Batch GeoCoding**. *The process of changing multiple addresses into a Geographical location is referred to as Batch GeoCoding.*

```
Google Maps API is not directly supporting BatchGeocoding. 
By using Google Maps API , We do geocode a single address at a time. 

To acheive BatchGeoCoding, We need to iterate a list of Address.(Not too difficult I think)
```

For best Practice : [GeoCode Example](http://jsbin.com/kogokoco/1/edit)

BatchGeocode Reference :

The following are online batch Geocoding sites. Have it for reference.

[Ref 1](http://www.findlatitudeandlongitude.com/batch-geocode/#.U2xzbHWSxJw)  , [Ref 2](http://www.gpsvisualizer.com/geocoder/)

[Working Demo](http://jsbin.com/hotomequ/1/)

**The Working demo is just a Proof of the Concept. It has to be refined in many ways. Please have a look at the reference to produce a better code.**

Comment: In the working demo, the code new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644); has latitude and longitude. But i don't know to whom city they belong? And also the working demo is not showing more than one location.

Comment: @user3185166: Please try to study the code. It is working fine. To make it work, at least try to Copy and paste the below "madurai:chennai:coimbatore"; Here COlON(:) is the delimiter to separate each city. If you dont know the lattitude and longtitude, Then show the entire the map. Updated the code in demo.